# Count Number of Values Less than Value in Another Column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

Given a dataframe like the one below, for each date in `Enrol Date`, how can I count the number of values in preceding rows in `Close Date` that are earlier? Ideally I would like to add the results as a new column.

| Class | Enrol Date | Close Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30/10/2003 | 05/12/2003 |
| A | 22/12/2003 | 23/09/2005 |
| A | 06/09/2005 | 29/09/2005 |
| A | 15/11/2005 | 07/12/2005 |
| A | 27/02/2006 | 28/03/2006 |

Desired result:

| Class | Enrol Date | Close Date | Prior Dates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30/10/2003 | 05/12/2003 | 0 |
| A | 22/12/2003 | 23/09/2005 | 1 |
| A | 06/09/2005 | 29/09/2005 | 1 |
| A | 15/11/2005 | 07/12/2005 | 3 |
| A | 27/02/2006 | 28/03/2006 | 4 |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible option using [`triu`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html) :

```
cols = ["Enrol Date", "Close Date"]
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_datetime, dayfirst=True)

enrol = df["Enrol Date"].to_numpy()
close = df["Close Date"].to_numpy()[:, None]

df["Prior Dates"] = np.triu(enrol>close).sum(0)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

  Class Enrol Date Close Date  Prior Dates
0     A 2003-10-30 2003-12-05            0
1     A 2003-12-22 2005-09-23            1
2     A 2005-09-06 2005-09-29            1
3     A 2005-11-15 2005-12-07            3
4     A 2006-02-27 2006-03-28            4
```

Comment: :D great minds think alike

Comment: We answered nearly at the same time. A glitch in the matrix :D

Comment: I believe OP might want the operation per group, though

Comment: Yes, the `Class` column makes the logic unclear. I'll update the answer if needed.

Comment: Thanks guys. Apologies for the confusion, there is no need to group.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) broadcasting with [`tril`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html), in a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) function:

```
def earlier_count(g):
    return pd.DataFrame({'count':
             np.tril(  g['Enrol Date'].to_numpy()[:,None]
                     > g['Close Date'].to_numpy()
                     ).sum(axis=1)},
             )

df['count'] = df.groupby('Class', group_keys=False).apply(earlier_count)
```

Output:

```
  Class Enrol Date Close Date  count
0     A 2003-10-30 2003-12-05      0
1     A 2003-12-22 2005-09-23      1
2     A 2005-09-06 2005-09-29      1
3     A 2005-11-15 2005-12-07      3
4     A 2006-02-27 2006-03-28      4
```

Answer (score 2):

The data you shared is sorted (on the `Close Date` column), so a binary search should be enough:

```py
df.assign(**{'Prior Dates' : df['Close Date'].searchsorted(df['Enrol Date'], side='right')})

  Class Enrol Date Close Date  Prior Dates
0     A 2003-10-30 2003-12-05            0
1     A 2003-12-22 2005-09-23            1
2     A 2005-09-06 2005-09-29            1
3     A 2005-11-15 2005-12-07            3
4     A 2006-02-27 2006-03-28            4
```

If your data is not sorted, or the `Class` column is relevant, kindly add more info to your original dataframe, and varying entries in the `Class` column (`B`, `C`, ...)

Comment: This seems to be a much more performant answer however it could be that the data is sorted on Enrol Date. Would this still work correctly if that is the case?

Comment: if the data is sorted on Enrol, then the binary search logic has to change. Let me think about that and see if there is a plausible solution

Comment: @Robsmith, I couldnt come up with a viable solution for cases where `Enrol` is the sorted column. I believe the other answers are more robust in this case. There is the `conditional_join`, as well, but the other answers are sufficient.